# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection AxiosError

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native

I am working on a react native project that has a signup and login screen. And the code below has the signup page where I encountered the error above as I couldn't connect to the MongoDB database. I was trying to reuse the *axios* functionality I had worked with on a react web app project even though I was not sure it would work. So if the *axios* methods can be reused can anyone help me edit and fix the error. Thanks.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button, Alert } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import tw from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames';
import UserLogin from './UserLogin';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";


const UserSign = () => {

  const [listOfUsers, setListOfUsers]= React.useState([]);
    const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
    const [phone, setPhone] = React.useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

    const [fetchError, setFetchError] = React.useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchUsers= async () =>{
        try{
          const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/user/getUsers")
          if(!response.ok) throw Error('Did not recieve expected data');
          const listUsers = await response.json();
          console.log(listUsers);
          setListOfUsers(listUsers);
          setFetchError(null);
        } catch(err){
          setFetchError(err.message)
        }
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        (async () => await fetchUsers())();
      }, 2000)
      //(async () => await fetchUsers())();
    }, [])

    const createUsers = () =>{
      axios.post("https:// /user/createUsers", {
        name, email, phone, password,
      }).then((response) =>{
        setListOfUsers([...listOfUsers,
        {
          name, email, phone, password,
        },
      ]);
        alert("User added!");
      });
    } 

//     fetch('http://localhost:3001/user/createUsers', {
//   method: 'POST',
//   headers: {
//     Accept: 'application/json',
//     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
//   },
//   body: JSON.stringify({
//     name: name,
//     password: password,
//   })
// })
//     }

   //const [name, onChangeName] = React.useState("");
   //const [email, onChangeEmail] = React.useState("");
   //const [phone, onChangeNumber] = React.useState("");
   //const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState("");
   //const [password, onChangePassword] = React.useState("");

  const navigation =useNavigation();
  return (
    <View style=
    {{
        top:80,
        left:20,
    }}>
      <Text> User Sign Up</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        //onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={name}
        placeholder="Username"
        
        onChange={(event) => {
                      setName(event.target.value);
                      }}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
       // onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={password}
        placeholder="Password"
       onChange={(event)=> {setPassword(event.target.value);}}
        
      />
       <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
       // onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={email}
        placeholder="Email"
        
       onChange={(event)=> {setEmail(event.target.value);}}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        //onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={phone}
        placeholder="Phone Number"
      //  keyboardType="numeric"
       onChange={(event) => {setPhone(event.target.value);}}
      />
   <TouchableOpacity
      style={tw `p-2 pl-6 pb-6 pt-4 bg-gray-600 m-2 w-40 rounded-full`}
      
        onPress={createUsers()
          
          //() => {
          
            
          //   Alert.alert(
          //     "New User!",
          //     "New User added. Now navigate to the Login page and enter your details or go back and change details" ,
          //      [
          //       {
          //       text: "Change",
          //       onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          //       style: "cancel"
          //     },
          //     { text: "Login", onPress: () => navigation.navigate(UserLogin) }
          //   ]
          //  );

         // }
        }
      >
        <Text style={{
        fontSize:18,
        left: 25
      }}>
            Sign-up
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    
  )
}

export default UserSign;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    width:300,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
   
  },
});
```

Comment: add a catch block to axios request, that should tell you the error

Answer (score 0):

Here is working template to get proper description of error using axios. Use axios request like this to get proper error

```
export const axiosConfig = {
headers: {
//Headers come here
},
};

let body={
//your data comes here
}

let response = await axios
.post(URL, body, axiosConfig)
.catch(function (error) {
  errorFunction(error);
  });
return response
```

Error function will be like this

```
function errorFunction(error) {
if (error.response) {
// The request was made and the server responded with a status code
// that falls out of the range of 2xx
console.log('\nerror data: ', error.response.data);
console.log('\nerror status: ', error.response.status);
console.log('\nerror header: ', error.response.headers);
}
else if (error.request) {
// The request was made but no response was received
// `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
// http.ClientRequest in node.js
console.log('\nerror request: ', error.request);
}
 else {
// Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
console.log('\nError message: ', error.message);
}
console.log('\nerror config: ', error.config);
}
```